# Unable to read Serial-Port (UART)

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, tty, uart

Below code is opening the second serial port and I am trying to read and write to it.Now I am using the console functionalities on the first port ( Tera Term Console ) to see the logs there (printf or dmesg ).

But I am not able to read from the port. The console hangs.

```
    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
    #define BUFF_SIZE 1024
    struct termios options;
    char to_write[1024];
    char to_read[1024];
    int bytes_written;

    int init_uart()
    {
        tcgetattr(fd, &options);

         /* Set Baud Rate */

        cfsetispeed( &options, B115200 );
        cfsetospeed( &options, B115200 );

        // Set the Charactor size

        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */

        // Set parity - No Parity (8N1)

        options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;/*no parity bit*/
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;/* One bit stop bit*/
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;/* 8 Bits Character length*/

        // Disable Hardware flowcontrol
        options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

        // Enable Raw Input
        options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

        // Disable Software Flow control
        options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

        // Chose raw (not processed) output
        options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

        if ( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options ) == -1 ){
            printf ("Error with tcsetattr = %s\n", strerror ( errno ) );
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int write_uart()
    {
        int i=0;
        while (i < BUFF_SIZE-2){
            to_write[i]='a';
            i++;
        }
        to_write[i]='\n';
        to_write[i+1]='\r';
        // Write to the port
        bytes_written = write(fd, to_write, BUFF_SIZE);

        if(bytes_written < BUFF_SIZE){
            fputs("write() of 1024 bytes failed!\n", stderr);   
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int
    read_port(void)
    {
        int n = read(fd, to_read, sizeof(BUFF_SIZE));
        if (n < 1024){
            fputs("read failed!\n", stderr);
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int i=0;
        fd = open("/dev/ttyS1",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
        if(fd == -1)
            perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS1\n");
        else
            printf("ttyS0 Opened successfully\n");
        if(init_uart())
            perror("open_port: Unable to initialize /dev/ttyS0 Port\n");
        else
            printf("Port Initialization is done successfuly\n");
        if(write_uart())
            perror("write_port: Unable to write to /dev/ttyS0 Port\n");
        else
            printf("Write to the port happened successfully\n");
        if(read_port())
            perror("read_port: Unable to read from /dev/ttyS0 Port\n");
        else
            printf("Read to the port happened successfully\n");
        close(fd);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Nice to see a serial port question that uses proper POSIX initialization and return code checking.  But (1) you did forget to check the return code of `tcgetattr()`.  (2) What device is this serial port connected to?  If there is no device on the other end of the serial link, then what to you expect to read? (3) Are you sure you want to put the port in raw mode?  Depending on the device that is connected (?), you could want/need canonical mode.  If it's a text device (as the `write()` output indicates), then you probably should use canonical instead of raw mode.

Answer (score 0):

@randomization, I think you have to configure control chars i.e. **c_cc[VTIME] and c_cc[VMIN]**. 
**VTIME:** The timer is started when read is called. read returns either when at least one byte of data is available, or when the timer expires. If the timer expires without any input becoming available, read returns 0. 
**VMIN:** read blocks until the lesser of MIN bytes or the number of bytes requested are available, and returns the lesser of these two values. 
Try configuring VMIN and VTIME and test your application. You can configure either of them. Will find good description about these things in man pages i.e. **#man termios**.

Comment: Yes, VTIME and VMIN should not be left unspecified when using non-canonical mode.  But your explanations of the timer and how/when a `read()` will return are incorrect.  You have simplified how these configurations work without specifying the values.  E.G. the timer can be from the start of the call (as you mention), OR an inter-character timer or no timer at all.  The OP is seeing the expected behavior for the default values of VMIN and VTIME.

Comment: @sawdust, explanation about VTIME and VMIN and about its return values are from the man page of termios.